# Get value of a property with propertyinfo object

Tags: vb.net, properties, propertyinfo

Is there a way to get value of a object properties with a propertyinfo object?

psudo code:

```
propertyinfoObject = Text
myobject.toCommand(propertyinfoObject)
```

The psudo code above should do the same as

```
myobject.Text
```

My goal is to create a simpel Properties form that will work on any object (Later I will use keywords to filter out what options I want the use to see).

My real code

```
Public Class PropertiesForm
Dim propertyInfoVar() As PropertyInfo
Dim Properties As New Form2
Dim listItem As New ListViewItem
Dim stringarray() As String
Public Sub New(ByRef sender As Object)



    propertyInfoVar = sender.GetType().GetProperties()
    For Each p In propertyInfoVar
        stringarray = {p.Name.ToString, #INSERT VALUE SOMEHOW HERE#}

        listItem = New ListViewItem(stringarray)
        Properties.ListView1.Items.Add(listItem)
    Next
    Properties.Visible = True
End Sub
```

EDIT
Just use propertyGrid as suggested below!

Comment: Not for nothing but doesnt the PropertyGrid already do all that?

Comment: :) You are so correct! I didn't know it existed. The .net framework is so big that it's easy to miss som critical stuff when you are new :). Maybe I should read my VB book from start to finish and not only jump around in it!

Answer (score 1):

The standard `PropertyGrid` already does all that for you. Filtering properties is not so obvious, here's how:

The control includes a `BrowsableAttributes` property which allows you to specify that only properties with the specified attribute value should be shown. You can use existing attributes, or custom ones.  This is specifically for tagging visible props:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class PropertyGridBrowsableAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Property Browsable As Boolean

    Public Sub New(b As Boolean)
        Browsable = b
    End Sub
End Class
```

Apply it to an Employee class to hide pay rates or anything else:

```
Public Class Employee
    <PropertyGridBrowsable(True)>
    Public Property FirstName As String
    ...
    <PropertyGridBrowsable(False)>
    Public Property PayRate As Decimal
    <PropertyGridBrowsable(False)>
    Public Property NationalInsuranceNumber As String
```

Test code:

```
Dim emp As New Employee With {.Dept = EmpDept.Manager,
                                    .FirstName = "Ziggy",
                                    .PayRate = 568.98D,
                                     ...
                                    .NationalInsuranceNumber = "1234567"
                                   }

propGrid.BrowsableAttributes = New AttributeCollection(New PropertyGridBrowsableAttribute(True))

propGrid.SelectedObject = emp
```

[image]

`BrowsableAttributes` is a collection, so you can add several.